Gradient moving background
I am trying to recreate the background of this site in a wordpress site I am creating. I think this comes with a lottie animation but not exactly sure. I can recreate a gradient transition as seen from this stackoverflow answer but still doesnt do the trick for me.
I can recreate it with something like
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top, #e66465, transparent),
            radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #4d9f0c, transparent);

but the closest thing I achieve is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xsf85m9c/
Any ideas?


body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: animateBackground 15s infinite linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes animateBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #e66465, #4d9f0c);
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff9a9e, #d4fc79);
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #c94b4b, #4b134f);
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 150% 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #4d9f0c, #e66465);
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200% 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff9a9e, #d4fc79);
  }
}




just edited take a look please

It is done using a canvas, not CSS. Let's create a similar effect. It's called plasma and I've adapted from here live demo
Of course, you can play with the parameters like I have.


function colorToRgb(color) {
  return {
    r: 255,
    g: 216 + 32 * Math.cos(color * Math.PI),
    b: 216 + 32 * Math.sin(color * Math.PI)
  };
}

function setPixel(ctx, x, y, rgb) {
  var index = (x + y * ctx.canvas.width) * 4;
  var pixels = ctx.canvasImageData.data;
  pixels[index] = rgb.r;
  pixels[index + 1] = rgb.g;
  pixels[index + 2] = rgb.b;
  pixels[index + 3] = 255;
}

function calcPlasma(ctx, x, y, time) {
  var size = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  var result = 0;

  result += Math.sin(x / size + time);
  result += Math.sin((y / size + time) / 2.0);
  result += Math.sin((x / size + y / size + time) / 2.0);

  var cx = x / size / 10 + 0.8 * Math.sin(time / 4);
  var cy = y / size / 10 + 0.8 * Math.cos(time / 3);
  result += Math.sin(Math.sqrt(100 * (cx * cx + cy * cy + 1)) + time);

  return result;
}


var t = 0.0;

function updateLoop(ctx) {
  var speed = 0.005;
  t = (t + speed);

  for (var x = 0; x < ctx.canvas.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < ctx.canvas.height; y++) {
      var color = calcPlasma(ctx, x, y, t);
      var rgb = colorToRgb(color);
      setPixel(ctx, x, y, rgb);
    }
  }

  ctx.canvasContext.putImageData(ctx.canvasImageData, 0, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    updateLoop(ctx);
  });
}


function initCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasImageData = canvasContext.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var context = {
    canvas: canvas,
    canvasContext: canvasContext,
    canvasImageData: canvasImageData
  };

  return context;
}

var context = initCanvas();
updateLoop(context);
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>


<h1>some text</h1>

<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>
<p>content of website</p>



